# How to create ACL roles automatically in Kafka while creating topics through Julieops?

Tags: apache-kafka

```
---
context: "context"
projects:
  - name: "foo"
    topics:
      - name: "mlocations"
        config:
          replication.factor: "3"
          num.partitions: "3"  
    services:
       - acl:
          - principal: "User:sa-d12np3"
            operation: "read"
                      
        
    ksql:
      artefacts:
        streams:
          - path: "/tmp/sendgrid.sql"          
            name: "sendgrid"
          - path: "/tmp/normalise.sql"          
            name: "normalise"
          - path: "/tmp/success.sql"          
            name: "success"
          - path: "/tmp/failed.sql"          
            name: "failed"        
    connectors:
      artefacts:
        - name: "DatagenSourceConnector_3"
          server: "connect0"
          path: "/tmp/source-jdbc.json"
```

I'm trying to create Topic, ksql, connectors so while creating topic I want to define ACL so to restrict/allow user for certain opertion(read,write) but above three task I able to create but ACL is not getting created, I'm running the script in CICD pipe line there its not showing any error sill ACL is not getting created.

Comment: What is the relationship with the MuleSoft tag?

Comment: Just thought whoever having MuleSoft knowledge they might know confluent , so for the better reach used MuleSoft tag

Comment: That's completely unrelated to the question.

Comment: I used that tag for better reach which im working on. I don't like  this kind of QA, if you know the solution please share here else you can ignore this question

Comment: Stackoverflow is a community curated site for developer Q&As. If a question is not clear you should expect comments asking for clarifications. If you would prefer not to be asked about your question, why would you expect others to answer it?